# Printing derived classes through a function

Tags: c++, class, printing, derived-class

I'm new to c++ because all throughout our lab activities we just use C# and I'm still trying get the gist of it. So our last lab, which uses c++, is to show our genealogy-our family tree- and my problem right now is printing. Can someone point out what's wrong in my function or why it's not printing and what's the best way to do it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class parent
{
    public:
        void setMom(string mom)
        {
            mother=mom;
        }

        void setDad(string dad)
        {
            father=dad;
        }

        string getDad(void)
        {
            return father;
        }

        string getMom(void)
        {
            return mother;
        }
    protected:
        string mother;
        string father;

};


class Member: public parent
{

    public:
        string name;

        Member()
        {

        }

        void setName(string kid)
        {
            name=kid;
        }

        void setStatus(string stat)
        {
            status=stat;
        }

        void setAge(int num)
        {
            age=num;
        }

        string getName()
        {
            return name;
        }

    private:
        string status;
        int age;

};


char addPerson()
{

    Member person;

    char mom[50];
    char dad[50];
    char kid[50];
    char stat[7];
    int num;


    cout<<"Name: ";
    cin>>kid;
    person.setName(kid);

    cout<<"Age: ";
    cin>>num;
    person.setAge(num);

    cout<<"Status(Living/Diseased): ";
    cin>>stat;
    person.setStatus(stat);

    cout<<"Father: ";
    cin>>dad;
    person.setDad(dad);

    cout<<"Mother: ";
    cin>>mom;
    person.setMom(mom);


}
```

my function for printing.

```
void showme()
{
    Member person;
    cout<<person.getMom();
}



//-----------------------------------------------------MAIN--------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int choice;

        cout<<"     1. Add member"<<"\n";
        cout<<"     2. Edit member"<<"\n";
        cout<<"     3. Show family tree"<<"\n";
        cout<<"     4. Exit"<<"\n";

        cin>>choice;

        if(choice==1)
        {
            addPerson();
        }

        else if(choice==2)
        {

        }

        else if(choice==3)
        {
            showme();

        }

        else if(choice==4)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When you say `Member person;    cout<<person.getMom();` you make a blank person and then print the contents.

Comment: Ohhhh... I see. Thank you.